# Visibilities permissions of children links in the Toolbar

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, users, navigation, toolbar

In a project started with the Thunder distribution, I'm currently managing the permission of the "editor" group.

By default, it only have access to the content menu, and it's a good thing. 
But what if I want to give  permission to some children links (and only some specific children) of the others menu ?

**Exemple:**

I give to this group the ability to access, add, edit and delete some taxonomy terms.

I can access to the relative admin page, but the `structure -> taxonomy` link in the [Admin Toolbar](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/admin_toolbar) is not appearing.

For now I have to manually create those links, but I think it's not the right way to do this because they will constitute duplicate link for the "administrator" group.

I suppose I need to give visibility right for the parent link "structure", but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a problem with the [Admin Toolbar](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/admin_toolbar) module, I think that you're not given the correct permissions.

In **Drupal >= 8.5** you need to give the following permissions:

- Use the administration pages and help
- Use the administration toolbar
- Tags: Create terms
- Tags: Delete terms
- Tags: Edit terms
- Access the taxonomy vocabulary overview page

In **Drupal < 8.5** as the *Access the taxonomy vocabulary overview page* not exists you need to assign the following permissions:

- Use the administration pages and help
- Use the administration toolbar
- Tags: Create terms
- Tags: Delete terms
- Tags: Edit terms
- Administer vocabularies and terms

The problem here is that the user will have the permission to create new vocabularies.

You can read about this in [New term overview and create permissions](https://www.drupal.org/node/2902390) and in [Add a dedicated permission to access the term overview page (without 'administer taxonomy' permission)](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1848686)

Comment: Using D8.4, I missed the "Use the administration pages and help" permission. Thanks for the resources too :)

Comment: @Cawet good luck with your project ;-)